# ANTD onFocus is not called every time while i open the select options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, antd

> onFocus   Called when focus

Here, I am using [antd](https://ant.design/components/select/) select Where i am using **onFocus** props which should actually be called whenever i clicked or open the select options. But it's not being called every time. What's the issue?

Actually i do have lot of select boxes in my project and i am using the same select box so whenever i focus the select boxes am fetching the particular selectbox options.

But since onFocus is not being called everytime I am facing issue.

[Codesandbox notworking example](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wave-5iu4b)

[codesandbox Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-grass-ckm4d)

onClick is not supported by Select. But the thing i needed is like onclick event so that everytime i click select box i want to fetch the data.

Comment: in the Codesandbox example Link its working fine

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar Actually I wanted to call onFocus everytime i clicked the selectbox. But i Found onDropdownVisibleChange where i can achive my functionality. Anyways, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I found the solution :
I can actually fetch data on

> onDropdownVisibleChange

Thankyou @[antdDesign](https://ant.design).